# Formatting a typescript date with the month written in full

Tags: typescript

I have a function like this in typescript

```js
setQuitDetails() {
    var currentDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
    this.TodaysDate = currentDate;
}
```

It returns the date like this `9/12/2017`

I want to return the date like this `September 12, 2017`

How can I achieve this in a typescript file?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if is running :

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var setQuitDetails = function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    this.TodaysDate = currentDate;
    var year = this.TodaysDate.getFullYear();
    var month = months[this.TodaysDate.getMonth()];
    var day = this.TodaysDate.getDay();
    var output = month + ' ' + day + ', ' + year;

   alert(output);
   return output;
}

setQuitDetails();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it via [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

```js
const options = { 
    month: 'long', 
    day: 'numeric', 
    year: 'numeric' 
}
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", options)));
```

==> `September 12, 2017`